# Creating automated maps for attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping

I understand that automated maps can be created using information in the attributes. I want to stop manually creating each map for land owned/managed (this is coded in the attribute tables).

How do I do this?

I am using QGIS 3.8.2

Comment: Hi there. You should user the atlas feature. More @ https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html and https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html

Comment: Check this also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgPOwm7GrIo

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Automating the creation of maps is the job of the Atlas feature, a real ace of QGIS when it comes to production.

It is very easy to master and ensures powerful results.

From any layout, access the Atlas feature by clicking on the `Altas` menu item:

[image]

There are also many tutorials around. Here are just two I liked:

https://gisgeography.com/how-to-create-qgis-atlas-mapbooks/

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html