# Iterating over layer features, zooming fully on map and exporting them as PNG images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I have 2 layers in QGIS map, One is raster layer and other is a vector layer having location of sites. Both are having same CRS. I want to zoom in to each feature in the vector layer and save the map. I am using QGIS 3.8 
I also tried the QTimer function as well as indicated on [How to loop through features in a layer, zoom to that feature and export to png](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202889/how-to-loop-through-features-in-a-layer-zoom-to-that-feature-and-export-to-png)
but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code

```
    ids =None
    def get_screenshots(layer):
        global id
        ids = layer.allFeatureIds()
        def savemap():
            qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
            layer.select(id)
            qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(400)
            qgis.utils.iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger() 
            qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("C:/Users/sumitsingh/
            Desktop/screenshots/pic_{}.png".format(id)     
            layer.deselect(id)
        for id in ids:
            savemap()

    l = iface.activeLayer()
    get_screenshots(l)
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't seem to be working". Is there an error message?

Comment: @Erik the loop runs through and a single image is saved multiple times in the folder. Also, I am not able to see changes in the in regard to the ZoomToSelected function

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the `Atlas` feature of QGIS, which does exactly what you need.

Automating the creation of maps is the job of the Atlas feature, a real ace of QGIS when it comes to production.

It is very easy to master and ensures powerful results.

From any layout, access the Atlas feature by clicking on the `Altas` menu item:

[image]

There are also many tutorials around. Here are just two I liked:

https://gisgeography.com/how-to-create-qgis-atlas-mapbooks/

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html

Disclosure: this is a duplicate *answer* of mine from [How do I create automated maps for attributes in QGIS 3.8.2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/338339/142513) ;)